# dependency mentioned in the pom is not being resolved

Tags: maven

I have a maven project, which was converted using m2e eclipse plugin and also have dependency on eclipse project. I have following dependency in my pom file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but they are still not being resolved at compile time and creating error.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
```

the above statement are not being resolved, it there any way, I can force the dependency from pom instead of using from .classpath

Comment: Are these dependencies inside `<dependencyManagement/>`?

Comment: Yes they are inside dependencyManagement

Comment: Have you updated your eclipse project? (select the project, hit ctrl+f5, this is for windows, not sure which are the keys for mac and linux)

Comment: __dependencyManagement__ does not declare dependencies per se, but versions and scopes for "real" dependencies declared outside of the __dependencyManagement__  tag

Answer (score 0):

Managed dependencies are not added to the classpath. 
The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs.

The solution: move those dependencies out of the management section